# Add previous value and carry the result in a list

Tags: python, list, sum, append

In Python, I am trying to add the to each number in a list, the value of the previous number and carry this sum through all of the list.

Given numbers = `[2, 5, 3, 2]`, the output should be `[2, 7, 10, 12]`, adding and carrying the sum until the end.

The following code is the one closest to the solution I managed to be, but I am getting `[0, 2, 7, 10, 12]`, since I am starting with zero, but cannot find a different solution.

```
numbers = [2, 5, 3, 2]

newList = [0]
sumN = 0
for n in range(0, len(numbers)):
 sumN += numbers[n]
 newList.append(sumN)
print(newList)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just remove the 0 from `newList = [0]`.

Comment: That was simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
new_list = []

for i in range(len(numbers)):
    new_list.append(numbers[i] + sum(numbers[:i]))
```

Comment: More clean. Thank you!